# Member filter in Twig

Tags: php, symfony, twig

I have some categories and item to them. I want to be able to delete only the categories to which items are not yet set. For example I have the category Books, but there are no concrete books added, so I can delete it. And I have the category Food and for it there are pizza, sandwich, apple - so I can't delete it. I'm thinking how it would be the best to do this.

```
<table class="table table table-striped spacer">
    {% for c in cat %}
        <tr>
            <td>
                {# If in edit mode, display edit form #}
                {% if id == c.id %}

                <form class="form-inline" action="{{ path('edit_category', {'id': c.id}) }}" method="post" {{ form_enctype(form) }}>

                    {% form_theme form 'EMBudgetTrackerBundle:Forms:inputs.html.twig' %}

                    {% for field in form %}
                    {{ form_row(field) }}
                    {% endfor %}

                    <button type="submit" class="btn"><i class="icon-ok"></i></button>

                </form>

                {# Else display the name #}
                {% else %}
                    {{ c.name }} 
                    <a href="{{ path('edit_category', {'id': c.id}) }}"><i class="icon-pencil"> </i></a> 
                    <a href="{{ path('delete_category', {'id': c.id}) }}"> <i class="icon-remove"></i></a> 
                {% endif %}
            </td>
        </tr>
    {% endfor %}
</table>
```

This is what I do for each category. What I want is if there are added items, no delete link to be provided. The only thing I could think of was to have two arrays - one with the categories with items, the others with the categories without items, and to to this for loop for both of them. But this will lead to code duplication - everything will be the same only the one loop won't have `<a href="{{ path('delete_category', {'id': c.id}) }}"> <i class="icon-remove"></i></a>` this row and it doesn't seem very elegant. i was thinking of something like

```
if(c.name not member of array_with_categories_without_items) 
then display the delete link
```

but I don't know if there is a way to do this. Can someone please give me some ideas? Thank you very much in advance! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depending on your application, there are a couple of things you can do.

My preference would be to show the delete links for all categories and do the validation on your actual delete page. This has a couple of added benefits:

- **Makes you think about this logic on the delete page**. Many people get caught up in hiding the link that they forget to actually check that logic when the user goes to delete a category. That means if they manually change a delete link to include the ID of a category with items, your application will gladly delete it.
- **Reduces the complexity of your entire application**. Not that a simple MySQL query makes your application more complex, but it definitely helps the view layer act a little cleaner without the conditional logic to show the link
- **Reduces server load**. You don't have to check for children in every category before printing the delete link (although, depending on your setup this may be a cheap operation)
- **It lets users know what's going on**. Otherwise, without knowing your application inside and out, they'll wonder why there's no delete link. Having a delete link that shows them an error if they click on it will tell them that they need to remove all children if they want to delete a category.

With that being said, you can just do this:

```
SELECT
    c.category_name,
    c.category_id,
    COUNT(f.food_id) AS children
FROM 
    categories c
    LEFT JOIN food f ON (c.category_id = f.food_id)
GROUP BY
    c.category_id
```

Which is obviously taking a guess at your database structure, but that'll get you a list of categories with a count of children for each